# Partial caching and fiddler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, fiddler, partial-caching

*I'm building a website  page with asp.net (webforms).*

I'm using partial caching (output caching) for a page. So `A` and `B` (user controls) are cached. (while the page is *not*). Is there any way I can see in `Fiddler` that `A` and `B` are retrieved from the *cache* while the page is not?

```
 ___________________
| Page              |
|   ____            |
|  +    +           |
|  |  A |(ascx)     |
|  +____+           |
|                   |
|                   |
|   ____            |
|  +    +           |
|  |  B |(ascx)     |
|  +____+           |
|                   |
|                   |
 ___________________
```

## edit

Lets say `A.ascx` contains only :

`<span>Hello A</span>`

and `B.ascx` contains only :

`<span>Hello B</span>`

and the output cache location is "*Private*" ( *for the ascx only !*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler shows all HTTP requests/responses as they are loaded by your browser.

If *A* and *B* are cached by the client, then when the page loads, you will not see requests for either *A* or *B* in Fiddler, **except on the very first page load**. On the first load, *A* and *B* will be downloaded (you will see them in Fiddler) and cached on the client.

Comment: A and B doesnt have requests. ( unless they have _images/css/js_ inside of them) in my case its just html containers.Also , Eric , it seems that pressing refresh VS retype the url have different behaviour. are they different ? ( my question are all from the book you advised - asp.net 4.5 ultra fast).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Doesn't have requests." Are you saying that these objects are cached *on the server side*? If so, Fiddler will see no difference (since it all comes from the server each time). Vis-a-vis your other question, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/07/08/technical-information-about-conditional-http-requests-and-the-refresh-button.aspx to understand how browsers treat F5 vs. renavigation (enter in the address bar).

Comment: I've added the Edit section. so youre saying that both html sections will be fetched from Browser cache ? (after >1 time...) And of course thank you for your replies.

Comment: Can you please answer my last comment ?

Comment: Let's step back. When you clear your cache and load your page, do you ever see a request for A.ascx or B.ascx in Fiddler's Web Sessions list?